# get all the children for a given xml in java

Tags: java, xml

I am basically following the example here

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/

So rather than doing something like

```
node.getChildText("firstname")
```

right??

this works fine..

But is there a way to get all the "keys" and then I can query that to get values?
Just like we do in parsing json..

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(value);
          for (Object key : json.keySet()) {
            Object val = json.get(key);
          }
```

rather than hardcoding keys and values?

Thanks

```
Code for reference:
package org.random_scripts;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

public class XMLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
      File xmlFile = new File("data.xml");

      try {

        Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
        Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
        List list = rootNode.getChildren("staff");

        List children = rootNode.getChildren();

        System.out.println(children);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

           Element node = (Element) list.get(i);

           System.out.println("First Name : " + node.getChildText("firstname"));
           System.out.println("Last Name : " + node.getChildText("lastname"));
           System.out.println("Nick Name : " + node.getChildText("nickname"));
           System.out.println("Salary : " + node.getChildText("salary"));

        }

      } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println(io.getMessage());
      } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
        System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really, since XML's only true key-value pairs are element attributes. XPath could potentially make your code simpler, though.

Comment: @MattBall Can you please elaborate?? how can i parse "any" xml data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you wanted to write out all of the children of the node, you could do something like this:

```
List children = rootNode.getChildren();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

    Element node = (Element) list.get(i);

    List dataNodes = node.getChildren();

    for (int j = 0; j < dataNodes.size(); ++j) {

        Element dataNode = (Element) dataNodes.get(j);
        System.out.println(dataNode.getName() + " : " + dataNode.getText());

    }

}
```

This would let you write out all of the children without knowing the names, with the only downside being that you wouldn't have "pretty" names for the fields (i.e. "First Name" instead of "firstname"). Of course, you'd have the same limitation in JSON - I don't know of an easy way to get pretty names for the fields unless your program has some knowledge about what the children are, which is the thing you seem to be trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The above code only provides the list of 1st level child under the tag. 
For example::

```
<parent>
  <child1>
    <childinternal></childinternal>
  </child1>
  <child2></child2>
</parent>
```

The above code only prints child1 and child2, if you want to print even the internal nodes in depth you have to do recursive call.

To find a child has more nodes in it use, jdom api `child.getContentSize()`, if its greater than 1 menas it has more nodes.